# Python crashes when loading very large file

Tags: python, file, crash

I have this error "Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow", when I load a very large .txt in memory. When i use small text file everything works perfect.
I want to load each line of my text file, split it by a "-" and put each [0] in a list, and each [1] in another list. So my text file would be like this:

```
aaaaa-bbbb
cccc-ddddddd
eeeee-fffff
```

So:

```
list1 = ["aaaaa", "cccc", "eeeee"]
list2 = ["bbbb", "ddddddd", "fffff"]
```

Comment: You might need to redesign your code to process the contents of the file as you read it, instead of storing it all in memory. While this may seem like a flippant answer, it's not: loading very large files in memory just leads to very inefficient code, and if you can think of a different way to structure things, you will potentially get huge efficiency benefits.

Comment: What is your definition of "a very large .txt in memory"? 10KB can still have thousands of lines but is very different to 1GB with millions of lines...

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the code in `terminal`
possibly It will run smoothly

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name',sep="-", header=None)
```

Comment: Does this solution address the problem of not having enough memory to load the whole file at once?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking in smaller subfile or wait after some number of lines.